# AJAX returning NaN

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

I am using AJAX call to pass a value to PHP and retrieve a value from PHP. The output i am getting in the console is NaN i am not aware what this means. Please help me rectify this and get the value back using AJAX

Script code:

```
window['channel']="OVERALL";
     $.ajax({
             method:"GET",
             url:"dash2.php",
             data:({channel:+channel}),
             success:function(data){
                    alert(data);
                    //console.log(data);
                    }
            });
```

PHP code:

```
<?php

$channel=$_GET['channel'];

echo json_encode($channel);



?>
```

Comment: NaN refers to Not a Number

Comment: I understood that. how to rectify this and get the passed value back on to the AJAX

Comment: Is channel supposed to be a number?

Answer (score 3):

NaN mean  Not a Number..

why do you have `+` operator there

```
data:({channel:+channel}), //here this is trying to convert it into number hence resulting in NAN
```

it should be

```
data:({channel:channel}),
```

taking a wild guess, it should be(if you are tryto pass that to server side (PHP)

```
data:{channel: window['channel']},
```

Answer (score 2):

```
+channel
```

`+` tries to convert "OVERALL" to number (result is NaN)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
data:({channel: +channel}),
```

Try this:

```
data:{channel: channel},
```

Answer (score 0):

Provide JSON datatype and check.

```
$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url:"dash2.php",
    dataType: 'json',
    data:({channel:+channel}),
    success:function(data){
        alert(data);
        //console.log(data);
    }
});
```